# Data Transfer to power Bi via pythonscript

Tags: powerbi, visualization, cockroachdb

I'm gonna connect to Cockroachdb direct and pickup data in power Bi with python script.
(There are not CocroachDB as a Dataresource in Power Bi)
what is the easiest und faster way to do that?
could you please guide me? I'm not profi in python

I have tried to connect DB with
psycopg2 and SQLALchere  but I think I did not do correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a guide on how to use Python scripts to import data:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts

This shouldn't be a problem in Power BI Desktop, but there are some restrictions wrt the available Python packages in the Power BI Service.